# Why does $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nz^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

If $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$ is convergent for all $z$, why does

$f'(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nz^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!} = f(z)$ ?

Shouldn't this mean that $z=n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{nz^{n-1}}{n!}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nz^{n-1}}{n!}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n}}{n!}
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

The first powers series starts with 1. Then you can perform a change $j=n-1$ and obtain the result. In fact, $f$ is the exponential function...